# Getting calculated percentages within group using SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a dataset:

```
Date

June 2011 
July 2011
Aug 2011
Sep 2011
Oct 2011
Jan 2012
Feb 2012
Mar 2012
Apr 2013
May 2013
```

that records down the date registered for each yearly project. (There are no project IDs however)

I would like to add in the additional variable Percentage, which represent the average progress made for that month. (For instance, if the project is registered for 4 months, then each month would progress incrementally by 25 %, (25,50,75,100)), specifically:

```
Percentage     Date
20             June 2011
40             July 2011
60             Aug 2011
80             Sep 2011
100            Oct 2011
33             Jan 2012
66             Feb 2012
100            Mar 2012
50             Apr 2013
100            May 2013
```

However, my main problem would be that I am unable to know the starting month (period) and ending month (period) for each project for each year.

Are there any functions in SQL to create the calculated percentages in this case? I thought of creating a year variable and further using an indicator to indicate the start/end of the progress, but could not move on further.

Thank you again!

Comment: Please  provide the full dataset  or provide sqlfiddle so that we can clearly understand what is required.

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: @srp, I have edited the question, hopes it brings more clarity.

Comment: @D-Shih, it is DB2

Comment: As I understand it: *There are no project id's, and no start dates, and no end dates*; but you want us to calculate different costs per month per project and add that up for you. We cannot invent vital missing data for you. I think you need to find the project ids, the start dates and the end dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query.

Getting `ROW_NUMBER()` by `year(dates)` on subquery.

then get the percent.

```
SELECT (FLOOR(CAST(T2.RK AS decimal) * 100/(
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS Totle
    FROM T 
    WHERE year(dates) = T2.dates)))  [Percentage],
    T2.dates as [years],
    T2.months as [months]
FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY year(dates) ORDER BY dates DESC) AS RK,
           year(dates) as dates,
           month(dates) as months
    FROM T
) AS T2 
GROUP BY T2.dates,T2.RK,T2.months
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Pseudo sql  to get what you want .  ?

```
select Year(date), Month(date)  ,  
 (select sum(Progress_percentage) from dataset b  where  b.date <=a.date ) as 
subquery_percentage
from dataset a
group by Year(date), Month(date)
```

Comment: Thanks! but in the case when I do not have the Progress_percentage, how would I be able to create the rolling sum?

Comment: Sub query is doing the rolling sum  for you :)  it is using less than or equal to  "<="

Comment: use need to compute the  progress my changing  the  "sum(<any expression>)"